# Outlook rule for body text exclude previous header

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, email-filter, rules

I hope nobody asked this before, because I could not find this anywhere about this in Google Search.
I am trying to create a simple Outlook rule regarding "Except if the body contains ..." as below

My Outlook rules:

> Except if the body contains John

So, for example the Email that I received from someone:

> Mon 3/14/2017 10:00 AM
> From: Smith, Adam
> To:Suzanna, Oh; Cenna, *John*; Man, Super; Duck, Donald *<-The John here is safe, not matched*
> Subject: RE: Yo Everyone!
>
> Dear Guys,
>
> OK. This is just an useless reply from me. Enjoy that!
>
> Regards,  Adam
>
> ---
>
> > From: Suzanna, Oh
> > Sent: Last Year, January 01, 1950 00:01 AM
> > To:
> >     Cenna, **John**; Smith, Adam; Man, Super; Duck, Donald *<-The John here is matched*
> > Subject: Yo
> >     Everyone!
> >
> > Dear All,
> >
> > How are you guys?
> >
> > Regards,  Suzanna

From the email above, my Outlook rule "Except if the body contains John" **is matched**, because of the **John** inside the *To email address* sent by previous email while someone replying the email.

What I want is to ***filter the real message body*** and not including the inside of email sections on previous emails.

I am using Outlook 2013 and Outlook 365/2016.

Comment: Why don't you use the "except if sent to people or public group" rule?

Comment: Because I would like only to move all emails without my name inside the email body into a folder. 
So, if there's my name inside body, it will stay in inbox.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that Outlook's search functionality isn't complex enough to do what you want. However, there are solutions of varying degrees.

**Simplest, dirtiest**

Change your rule so that it reads "Except if the body contains John and does not contain **Cenna, John;**". Of course if this string is found in the body this e-mail will be filtered out.

**Middle, requires a bit of tech know-how**

Have a look at [this thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/7196cf81-7822-48bd-8ac5-96ae46566255/how-to-show-email-address-not-just-name-in-from-and-to-fields?forum=outlook) which talks about including e-mail addresses in internal e-mails. I've got this by default for internal e-mails in 2013, and it should be case for 2016 without any changes. This allows to filter by "Except if the body contains John and does not contain **John.Cenna@mycompany.com**"

**Hardcore**

Check out [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865500/regular-expression-rules-in-outlook-2007) about using Regex in Outlook. After that you can go nuts with customer rules - e.g. to deal with your scenario, ignore lines with are "To:.*John", "cc:.*John" etc

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For Simplest and Middle one, the problem is I don't see any "does not contain" rule on my side. For Hardcore one, I prefer not to use. 
http://i.imgur.com/Hj0yRqDl.jpg